# Ayuda con un ejemplo usando patrones de diseño

Tags: java, c#, patrones-de-diseño

A ver si alguien me puede dar una mano con este ejemplo:
Se realiza una venta de productos, los productos pueden ser A,B, o C, y se le puede vender a clientes X, Y, y a cada producto se le hace un descuento dependiendo del producto que sea y el cliente que lo compre, por lo que tengo 6 reglas distintas. 
Yo pense en armar un strategy descuento, y las 6 combinaciones tendrian cada una una concreteStrategy, lo que quiero es tener en la clase venta un metodo que me calcule el descuento total, tomando una lista de productos y que use esas strategys, el problema es como hago para que decida ante un producto y cliente la strategy a usar.
Aclaro: no quiero usar condicionales, necesito que sea escalable.

Gracias.

Comment: Pones dos etiquetas java y c# en que lenguaje lo piensas hacer, y cual es el problem.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, por curiosidad hermano, ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

@Bryam tal vez puedas usar el polimorfismo es decir usar un método en relación al tipo de objeto sobre el que se invoca.

Miremos este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el se crea una clase Product, con nombre y estrategia de pago.

Entonces los procesadores de texto usan el newWordProcessor, de forma que para pagar un procesador de texto lo haces de una vez.

Luego la newSpreadSheet se refiere a las hojas de cáculo y permite fraccionar el pago en tres plazos, una ahora, otro en 60 dias y otro en 90 dias.

Por último las bases de datos permiten repartir el pago entre ahora, 30 días y 60 días.

Para entenderlo de forma gráfica la iidea es la que tu comentas el patrón Strategy:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrías una interfaz en tu caso DescuentoStrategy con 6 implementaciones.

Ambas imágenes son sacadas del libro de martin Fowler: Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola @Enoy  te sugerimos responder a preguntas que sean realizadas de acuerdo a lo dictado en el [help], de otra forma la pregunta solo será útil para el que pregunta y no para la comunidad y de esta forma obtendrías reputación para tus contribuciones, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me acabo de topar con un problema parecido y lo resolví así :

-https://github.com/Emmanuel93/StrategyExample.

En este caso hay diferentes tipos de estrategias, tanto para clientes (por que es descuento por venta) y para productos. *Evitar las condicionales es imposible* en algún lugar tienes que decidir que estrategia vas a tomar. Te recomiendo que manejes una capa de reglas de negocio para que tus modelos sean independientes del negocio y así totalmente `reutilizables`.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega lo esencial del enlace que agregas, revisar [answer], saludos.